# 80's or 90's Movie about a desert science lab

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a movie from when I was a kid about a science lab in the desert and it really creeped me out. Being older, I'd love to re-watch it and see, probably, how corny it is.

There's been no contact from the desert lab so a recovery team is sent in. The recovery team comes in and they hear or see someone in the ventilation ducts. I believe one of the researchers or a person was experimented on and he killed everyone.

I remember the ending where the survivors are flying away in a small plane and the guy/ mutant is on the wing of the plane.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [Mind Ripper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_Ripper) from 1995?

> Set in a remote desert location, government scientists perform
>   reanimation experiments in an underground nuclear facility. The goal
>   is to create a superhuman. Their first subject, "Thor", is a specimen
>   from a suicide found in the desert. In the attempts to bring Thor
>   back, an uncontrollable creature is unleashed. The next morning, a
>   scientist named Alex calls Stockton, one of the overseers of the
>   project, at his home and after an argument, Stockton eventually
>   decides to visit the facility by plane. His son Scott, his daughter
>   Wendy, and Wendy's boyfriend Mark join him.

The film ends with the titular character hanging off of the plane trying to kill the occupants.

Comment: I agree that this might be the answer.  RiffTrax (a successor to Mystery Science Theater 3000) has done this movie.  You can see a short clip of it here: https://www.rifftrax.com/mind-ripper

Comment: That could be it. I am going to try to watch it tonight and I will let you know. Looks corny lol. Thank you!

Comment: @E.Johnson - And was it the right answer?